Google Recaptcha block submit on Firefox 125.0.3 x64
After updating Firefox, Google ReCaptcha2 stopped working on my sites (I use the invisible version). Then I checked the version from the official website and it doesn’t work either.
I read about self = this on stackoverflow, but this also does not help on my sites.
After clicking, nothing happens, and there is an error in the console.
Has anyone encountered this?
The same behavior here https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo, an error is displayed and loading... loading... loading.
Error in console is like:
UncaughtObject { stack: "z<@https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/WQcDpAcHn0sjM6ZiVkU8JwNH/recaptcha__ru.js:470:201\nH<@https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/WQcDpAcHn0sjM6ZiVkU8JwNH/recaptcha__ru.js:258:...
from https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/WQcDpAcHn0sjM6ZiVkU8JwNH/recaptcha__ru.js line 448:1
Tested on absolutely clean Firefox without plugins, with security turned off, without cookies and account.
When i start browsing from Holland IP via VPN the problem are solving.
In Chrome, Edge ReCaptcha2 working fine.
Solved. 03.05. Google fixed as i see, since I didn’t do anything and the FireFox version didn’t change.

The error has been fixed. It’s as if Google fixed it, since I didn’t do anything and the FireFox version didn’t change.

It would appear that switching the user agent away from firefox resolves this, which means Google is blocking recaptcha requests from user agents ~firefox at the moment.
You can install a user agent switcher plugin in firefox to switch to anything reporting as chrome or safari and the recaptcha works again. Obviously not a solution for end-users.
This, hopefully, is a temporary mixup on their end.

"Obviously not a solution for end-users.", This option works, I forgot to mention it. But the meaning remains the same.
